# The oozie job is not submitting

Tags: hadoop, oozie

I have checked for oozie service at 11000. It is connecting.
But at the time of submitting job console is stuck.
Command used for submitting is

```
oozie/bin/oozie job -submit -config /tmp/config.properties -oozie http://127.0.0.1:11000/oozie
```

I have also checked logs for errors. There isnt any.

Comment: `oozie job -oozie http://127.0.0.1:11000/oozie -start <wf-id>`

Comment: Its not submitting. so I dont know its wf-id

Comment: I hope you are able to open the UI with the above url. There must be something in the logs. check the oozie.log, also other wise try restarting the service and tail the log at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have mentioned wrong yarn port and ip address in config file. Thats why it was not connecting to yarn and it was not submitting. I have updated it and its working fine.

Comment: Did you mean `job-tracker` property was wrong? But I think, It should be able to submit the workflow to the oozie server. It should not fail to do that.

Comment: Yes both namenode and job-tracker ips were wrong. After very long time it thew error about wrong ips.

Comment: Yes. Which mean you were able to submit the workflow to oozie server, not getting executed. The error was in the execution of the workflow not in the submission. I guess, that was the case. right?

Comment: No It was in submission. I never got wf-id. Each time it failed for submission.

Comment: I tried with the wrong name-node, it fails while the submission and point out the provided host:port, but in case of wrong job-tracker, it submits successfully but the job will fail (may be after a long time, after all retries). Good that it is working now for you.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the -submit command.  You need to use -run for the job to submit.  You should get a workflow id when you submit.  This is the command you should run:

```
oozie/bin/oozie job -run -config /tmp/config.properties -oozie http://127.0.0.1:11000/oozie
```

You can check the status of the job by running:

```
oozie job -oozie http://localhost:11000/oozie -info <wfid>
```

Comment: same is happening for oozie/bin/oozie job -run -config /tmp/config.properties -oozie http://127.0.0.1:11000/oozie command